# Callback once Activity in another process has started?

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, start-activity

If I do startActivity() on an Activity in another process; is there a good way to receive a callback at the starting point (starting the new Activity form a background service) that the new Activity really has started? I mean I can make a broadcast but that seems lame. Is there a better way for this?

Comment: What about an interface?

Comment: How do you mean? It is another process; how would I go about it?

Comment: The way to do this is to have a service. When the first activity starts bind it with the service. In the service create a handler (the handler which you will use in  creating the Messenger object) which contains an interface call to the first activity in its handleMessage(). On the new activity which starts in a new thread, bind with the same service and call the handler using the Messenger object. Therefore communication will occur through a Handler and data will be transfered in a Message object. If you didn't get it, reply here.

Comment: Excellent answer. Please put as answer so I can accept it as formal answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are asking about is ipc. Google it for more info.

To achieve this you need to create a sevice class and bind the two activities to it.

An example Service class would look like this.

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    //create a handler that will be used to handle messages
    //this is just an example. Use static handlers
    final Handler handler=new Handler(){
         public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            //I've just created a static feild.Check below.
            MyFirstActivity.activity.seconActivityStarted();
         }
    }

    //create a Messenger object
    Messenger messenger=new Messenger(handler);

    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
       return messenger.getBinder()
    }
}
```

Now things are simple.

Now you have to bind the first activity with the servie.

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //for the time being I'll just create a static field that will be used.
    //you can use an interface
    static MyFirstActivity activity;
    //create a ServiceConnection
    ServiceConnection connection=new ServiceConnection(/*contents of the service connection */);

   public void onStart(){
       super.onStart();
       activity=this;
       bindService(new Intent(this,MyService.class),connection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
   }

   //following method will be called by the handler in the service
   public void secondActivityStarted(){
       //some code
   }

   //you have to handle the activity lifecycle with the bound service.
   //right now its described here

}
```

Now the second activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //create a ServiceConnection
    ServiceCOnnection serviceConnection=new ServiceConnection(){
         //call the handler at onServiceConnected
         public void onServiceCOnnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service){
              Messenger messenger=new Messenger(service);
              //compose a Message object as you like
              messenger.send(new Message());
         }
    };

    //bind this activity to the same service
    public void onStart(){
       super.onStart();
       bindService(new Intent(this,com.package.name.MySerice.class),serviceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

That's it. Modify this according to the requirements.

P.S.Above mentioned code is just working structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you do startActivity() on an Activity in same or another process (and assuming the second activity starts), the calling Activity will go in to first PAUSED, and then STOPPED state. Which means no callback would be processed. However, you can call startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and receive onActivityResult() callback.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to stop the started Activity, right? I want it to keep running.

Comment: By Android design ONLY the foreground Activity is the running Activity, and the background Activities are automatically pushed to Stopped state or even Destroyed as per system resource requirement.

Comment: I don't think that you can keep the first Activity running

Comment: OK, wrong of me. The Activity is actually started from a background service.

Comment: Since you need to do inter process communication, you can create an interface for the service with a Messenger https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Answer (score 0):

Add a class MyApplication that extends Application and mention in your Manifest too and than put two boolean variables in it.

```
      private static boolean activityVisible;

  public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
}

public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
}
 public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
}
```

and so now you can use call activityPaused() when you do startActivity() on onPause() and onStop() of current activity, and when you return back to same activity do call activityResumed() in overriden onResume() method.

Now, by using MyApplication.isActivityVisible() you can get to know whether your Activity is running or paused.